# NPM build works, NPM start does not (create-react-app)

Tags: npm, http-status-code-404, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am using create-react-app. When I first run 'npm start' everything works fine. When I cancel the process, however, localhost begins to return 404.

Here's my terminal:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/NameSelection.jsx
  Line 21:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

./src/components/RelationshipSelection.jsx
  Line 25:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='           eqeqeq
  Line 99:   'options' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/PreferenceSelection.jsx
  Line 5:  'url' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

^C
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:test dcaine$ yarn start
yarn run v1.9.2
$ serve -s build

   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                  │
   │   Serving!                                       │
   │                                                  │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000      │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.73:5000   │
   │                                                  │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!             │
   │                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant but: When I initially run yarn start it's on port 3000, after cancelling it changes to 5000.

When I run `npm build` followed by `npm start` then the app will start and build any changes I have made, but any subsequent changes will not be reflected in the app (until I repeat this process).

What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can occur when you mix using npm and yarn, maybe? What I did to fix this:

1. Delete node_modules
2. Re-add modules using `yarn add`
3. `yarn start`

Works fine now